# On mouse over surround element with additional elements without moving it

Tags: css, gwt, gwtquery

i need some pointers here because i don't really know what to look for.
The project is in gwt and is using gwtquery.

I have this page with some elements and when the mouse overs an element it changes showing additional infos, let's call it header. When the mouse goes out of the header (which has some buttons so it need to stay visible once shown) it returns invisible.

The problem is that when the header is made visible all the elements of the page change position because my element changes in dimension. What i wish to do is to keep the element in the same position and overlap the header over everything with z-index.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about GWT at first hand. It's mostly about general concepts of elements positioning and layout building for html pages. You should start from something like http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp
And then find the appropriate tools in GWT framework or in third party libraries that are available.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I just mentioned it because maybe there's something built-in. Looking into positioning with plain css.